# Emacs 24 keybindings for tex

Tags: key-bindings, emacs24.4

This weekend I've upgrade from emacs 23 to emacs 24 (with `apt-get install emacs24`) and that broke some of the regular keybindings.

- `C-x C-o` used to trigger `tex-latex-block` and `C-x C-e` used to trigger `tex-close-latex-block`. The Emacs 24 manual states that these keybindings still work (see section 22.10.2), but instead, `C-x C-e` triggers `Environment type` and `C-x C-o` isn't bound to anything. I've tried to get the old keybindings back through `M-x global-set-key RET key cmd RET`, but I can't get things to work, even when I restart emacs.
- With Emacs 23, I would use `C-c C-f` to trigger `latex`, and then `C-c C-c` to choose between `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `dvips`, and `ps2pdf` (this is useful because, depending on the document I am working on, I might want to run either `pdflatex` alone or a `latex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` sequence). Now, `C-c C-f` isn't tied to anything, and `C-c C-c` simply doesn't recognize `dvips` or `ps2pdf` at all. Again, trying to get the old keybindings back fails.

So, the question here is, how can I get Emacs behaving the way it used to?

Answer (score 4):

Many installations of emacs 24 have the AUCTeX package activated in the default set-up.  The keybindings you are seeing come from that package, and you should look at its manual instead to find descriptions of them.

If you don't wish to use AUCTeX, then may be you can uninstall it by running `list-packages` and deleting the package. If not then may be https://stackoverflow.com/q/10573067/4050592 will help you remove the package.